# How can I change which computer a Tab Rocket label refers to?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I use the [Tab Rocket](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lagnjeopiknlgcenffgjmnpjkegjcnoo) extension for Chrome to send browser tabs between my home and work computers. My laptop at work was configured with the label "Work laptop," but it has died and been replaced with a new one. I'd like the new laptop to have the same Tab Rocket label as the old one, but the extension won't let me; it says, "Computer name already exists." The old laptop will never boot again, so how can I reuse its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab Rocket works by creating bookmarks in folders corresponding to each computer. When the target computer notices a new bookmark in that folder, it opens the link and deletes the bookmark.

To take a name from another computer and associate it with the current computer, open Chrome's Bookmark Manager, find the bookmark folder for that computer, and delete it. Tab Rocket keeps its folders in a group called "TabRocket - do not delete." Don't delete that folder, but find the folder *inside* it named "Work laptop" and delete it. (If there are still bookmarks in it, you may want to visit each of them beforehand so you don't lose them.) Once the folder is gone, Tab Rocket will let you use the name on the current computer.